# xwiki line break prevents xwiki syntax formatting

Tags: syntax, xwiki

So i have an object with a textarea property which i am giving a text with xwiki syntax in it to make a line break according to the documentation
[XWiki Syntax 2.1: New Line/Line Breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ3I). Below is the text I am uploading.

```
=Beschreibung Ablauf der Notfallübung=\\==Planung==\\Um die Sicherheit im Brandfall zu erhöhen veranstaltet ...
```

**The problem is, that the first heading gets formated right but everything after the line breaks looses its formatting. How can i prevent that from happening?**

Comment: Can you insert an empty line between the headings?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the double backslash line break (\\) to a simple line break (\n) and it worked accordingly. Still don't know why it didn't work though. Not a good answer for the question I know but an working alternative.